# Not yet to get married

Tags: nikah, women

Asalamu aleykum warahmatuallhi wabarakaatuhu

My question is that If a good guy comes to you and propose for you can you say no cause you not ready yet and you know that this person and you will not get along with each other cause he is really different to you

Comment: @goldPseudo I think the close reason is wrong it's clear what the OP asks but i guess we will find duplicates! OP (She) wants to know if she can refute a proposal for some reasons!

Answer (score 6):

Marriage is something you plan on doing as a life-long act. And from the hadeeth, we know that out of the 4 reasons for marrying, the best is the one who chooses their spouse for piety.

But even if a person is pious, there's no way you will commit to marriage if you don't like the person. You may have your personal reasons for liking or disliking someone. If you don't like the person who is proposing, then you're free to say no.